# Center-align elements on the same line and in the same container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way to left-align, center-align, and right-align elements on the same line without separating the elements into separate containers. To right-align an element, I know I can float the element by using `pull-right` directly on the element; but I'm having trouble centering an element. I'm using bootstrap but a pure css solution would be fine as well.

In other words, I know this works: https://jsfiddle.net/u69rz06s/3/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <button>Button 1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
    <button>Button 2</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
    <button>Button 3</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I looking for a solution that looks something like this (however, this currently does not work): https://jsfiddle.net/pvw1qL5v/2/

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button style="text-align: center;">Button 2</button>
  <button class="pull-right">Button 3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`display: flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [`justify-content: space-between`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/).

```js
.col-xs-12 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button>Button 1</button>
      <button>Button 2</button>
      <button>Button 3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gnnfv2jr/1/)

Comment: Perfect! I've never heard of `flex` before. Is this commonly used? And do front-end framewords like bootstrap and foundation use it (it looks like [bootstrap v4 does](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment))?

Comment: I think you answered your own question :)